# Is it possible to consume Odoo inventory via the Web Service API?

Tags: odoo

Is it possible for an external application to update inventory items tracked within Odoo and mark them as shipped to a specific customer?

If so, what's the best way to do that?  Via the XML-RPC web service API?  Is there a REST API?

The XML-RPC web API seems to imply that this is possible, but it doesn't list the database entities upon which the API is allowed to act. Can this API act on any DB entity?

Thanks in advance for your time.

Comment: Take a look in the odoo web service api documentation https://www.odoo.com/documentation/10.0/api_integration.html

Answer (score 1):

From what I've seen, there isn't a standing RESTful API for Odoo. There is an API for communicating with Odoo which can be found [here](https://www.odoo.com/documentation/9.0/api_integration.html). As well as tutorials on how to implement these features [here](https://www.odoo.com/documentation/9.0/).

If you are in need of a RESTful API then I would provision your own server and have it act as a reverse proxy which communicates through the RESTful model. This way you could dynamically connect multiple clients to multiple DB instances from one point. If you're comfortable with nodejs [here](https://github.com/4yopping/node-odoo) is an npm module which just makes HTTP posts to the database with Remote Procedure Calls which have been JSON-ified. This combined with express would offer you a quick solution for an Odoo RESTful API.

That module, however, doesn't seem extensively maintained but the logic is relatively easy to follow and you could fabricate your own quickly.

Answer (score 0):

You can try with the `XML-RPC` API of the object `stock.quant`
You will have to provide the `location_id` and request the product_id and quantity.